# Reversed audio channels in Moto G2 on Marshmallow (6.0)

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, motorola-moto-g2

So it appears that all Moto G2 updated to Marshmallow have the audio channels swapped (left plays right and right plays left), which is quite an annoyance.
Do you think there's a way to fix this by editing system files somehow? I'm not really hoping to wait for a patch, since this issue turns out to have been detected a long time ago during soak tests.